# Ninject binding when controller has attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have a controller

```
[MyAttribute]
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public MyController(InterfaceA a, InterfaceB b)
    {
    }
}
```

I wanted InterfaceA always to bind to ClassA if the request is coming from a controller with the MyAttribute. So I did a call.

```
Bind<InterfaceA>.To<ClassA>().WhenClassHas<MyAttribute>();
```

One of the instantiations of InterfaceB, ClassB, has a constructor like this.

```
public ClassB(InterfaceC c)
```

I want InterfaceC to bind to Class C when the called controller had the MyAttribute. However, my previous binding won't work, because the parent class is an intermediary class, not the controller itself. Is there anyway to write the binding so it will work from anywhere provided the calling controller had the attribute?

**Edit:** My solution using Remo's advice

```
public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<TBinding> WhenControllerHasAttribute<TBinding>(this IBindingWhenSyntax<TBinding> instance, Type type)
{
    Func<IRequest, bool> hasAttribute = (request) =>
    {
        while (request.ParentRequest.Target != null)
        {
            request = request.ParentRequest;
        }
        return request.Target.Member.ReflectedType.IsDefined(type, false);
    };
    return instance.When(hasAttribute);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can you must use `When(Func<IRequest, bool> condition)` instead and write some custom code.

WhenClassHas uses the following Func:

```
request => request.Target.Member.ReflectedType.HasAttribute(attributeType)
```

You have to extend this and iterate up in the injection context using `request.ParentRequest`

Comment: Thank you, it's great that you actively answer questions on here.

Comment: I tried changing the InterfaceB in my example to getting set through property injection, and in this case my solution failed to work. Is my solution wrong/ can I rewrite it to handle all types of injection?